# Use function provided by plugin only if plugin is installed and enabled

Tags: templating, plugins

I want to use [asset rev](https://github.com/clubstudioltd/craft-asset-rev) in my template, but only if plugin is installed and enabled:

```
    {% if craft.app.plugins.getPlugin('assetrev') is not null and craft.app.plugins.getPlugin('assetrev').isInstalled %}
        {% set fileName = rev(file) %}
    {% else %}
        {% set fileName = file %}
    {% endif %}
```

Hovewer when i disable plugin, mere existence of `rev` function in my template, still causes error.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if the plugin is installed and enabled with:

```
{% if craft.app.plugins.isPluginEnabled('assetrev') %}
  {% set fileName = rev(file) %}
{% else %}
  {% set fileName = file %}
{% endif %}
```

you won't need the extra check `craft.app.plugins.isPluginInstalled('assetrev')` then.

[isPluginEnabled()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-plugins.html#method-ispluginenabled):

> Returns whether a given plugin is installed and enabled.

Comment: true, but using `rev` in templates still causes error.